# VBA - Each checkbox in loop react to when one changes, how to stop?

Tags: excel, checkbox, vba

I'm new to VBA. I searched for a long time to find a way to have indefinite (varying) amount of ActiveX checkboxes but without the corresponding amount of _click subs but I couldn't make it work.

I thought I found a way around it with Form Controls, but it doesn't seem to work perfectly. This is my code to click cbxReady (a checkbox when a project is ready, can only be ticked if cbxStart is ticked):

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For s = 1 To LastRow - 2
    If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("cbxReady" & s).Value = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(s + 2, "A").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("cbxReady" & s).Value = -4146 Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(s + 2, "A").Interior.Color = RGB(218, 238, 243)
    End If
Next
```

And this is cbxStart:

```
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

For s = 1 To LastRow - 2
    If ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("cbxStart" & s).Value = 1 Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(s + 2, "A").Interior.Color = RGB(218, 238, 243)
        With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("cbxReady" & s)
            .Enabled = True
            .Value = -4146
        End With
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("cbxStart" & s).Value = -4146 Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(s + 2, "A").Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        With ActiveSheet.CheckBoxes("cbxReady" & s)
            .Enabled = False
            .Value = 2
        End With
    End If
Next
```

The idea was that the checkboxes are named cbxStart and cbxReady from 1 to whatever, and when I click cbxStart, the cell in column A (indicating a status of a project by colorcoding) will turn blue, then if I click cbxReady then it will turn yellow. So far so good.

However, this happened:
first row, both are ticked, colour is yellow, all is good;
second row, both are unticked, I tick cbxStart, it turns blue BUT first row turns blue too, as well as its cbxReady unticks.

So basically, even though the checkboxes are named differently, every checkbox reacts to the untick event.

Can someone help me with this please? If it's easier with ActiveX I'd appreciate that too, I'd just like to have one piece of code per checkbox type because I don't know how many I will have and I'd like them to reference one cbxStart_click() and one cbxReady_click().

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The trick to doing this is to have a class that handles the Click event.

**MyCheckBox Class**

```
Private WithEvents Check  As MSForms.CheckBox

Private Sub Check_Click()
    MsgBox Check.Object.Value
End Sub

Public Sub SetCheckBox(ck As OLEObject)
    Set Check = ck.Object
End Sub
```

Next you'll need to add each check to new MyCheckBox class and add the MyCheckBox to a module level collection.

```
Public Checks As Collection

Private Sub AddCheckboxes()
    Dim o As OLEObject
    Dim ck As MyCheckBox
    Set Checks = New Collection
    For Each o In ActiveSheet.OLEObjects
        Set ck = New MyCheckBox
        ck.SetCheckBox o
        Checks.Add ck
    Next
End Sub
```

Now whenever a checkbox is clicked the `Private Sub Check_Click()` will be called.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This is for Forms though, right? I have to assign a macro to them if it is but I don't have the macro in the list even if I set it to normal sub.